# Run a shell script inside a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a shell script like create.sh inside a docker container.
I connected to container like below.

```
docker exec -it --user=root <container_id> /bin/sh
```

and when i try to run the script inside the container i am getting an error .

```
sh-4.2# sh create.sh
create.sh: line 1: !/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit the question and add the contents of `create.sh` file. The most probable thing is what @Faeeria said in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You must have put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your .sh script. So it searches for `/bin/bash` to run this script, but cannot find it because bash is not installed.

Comment: what should i put , to run the script

Comment: You seem to be using `/bin/sh`, you can either put that or put nothing (since you are already using sh, but that's not the best idea)

Comment: i have connected to container , like below but  docker exec -it --user=root <id> / bin/bash   but , i get permission denied even though i am root [root@ /]# ./create.sh
bash: ./create.sh: Permission denied  The permissions are , -rw-r--r--.   1 root root    62 Mar 30  2020 create.sh

Comment: Your permissions are `rw-r--r--`, meaning you don't have the execution permission, meaning your file is not executable even if you are root. You should give the file this permission : `chmod u+x create.sh`. I would advise that you follow some kind of course on Linux systems, it seems that you are missing some basic knowledge.